# Create a cookie via Hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

According to the hapi framework docs [here](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/cookies?lang=en_US), and tutorial [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-manage-cookies-and-http-states-across-requests), in order to create a cookie you must first configure the server by calling server.state(...) immediately after creating the server.

I have the following code

```
const server = new hapi.Server();

try {
    server.state('session', {
        ttl: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        encoding: 'base64json'
    })
} catch (err) {
    server.app.cookieError = err
}
```

Which results in the following error:

```
Error: Cannot add state without a connection
```

I have followed the docs and other tutorials exactly, this error should not be happening, i have searched google for the error text and it brings up zero results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way, you need to configure your server with connection and then start it.

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost'});

server.state('session', {
    ttl: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    encoding: 'base64json'
})

server.start((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
})
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are correct since the intellisense comments for server.connection specifically mention server.state. However if i call server.connection, it takes the whole app down with an HTTP 503

Comment: I don't understand your question, the answers is there, if you want another answer you need to improve your question.

Comment: ignore what i said, i mistakenly added a new connection rather than simply moving my existing connection up a few lines. Thank you for your answer, works perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to start the server by calling server.connection method before you initiate the state.